# Como gerar um relatório PDF em Angular

Tags: angular, pdf

Olá, Gostaria de gerar relatórios em PDF usando o Angular consumindo dados do firebase.

É possível fazer relatórios de multiplas páginas a partir de HTML ou utilizando TypeScript? Por favor me ajudem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma lista de soluções, você necessitará estruturar o conteúdo e utilizar alguma dessa possibilidades.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-pdf

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html5-to-pdf

https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-html2pdf

http://pdfmake.org/

Recomendo a leitura da documentação de cada um, assim poderá determinar qual a melhor solução, dado que as informações e estrutura do seu projeto não são divulgadas na pergunta. :)

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou verificar cada uma delas!

Comment: caso não consiga chamar